# Как изменить размер атласа?

Tags: спрайт, cocos2d

Имею файл c расширением .gaf (в нем есть sprite sheet) с определенными размерами. Как можно увеличить эти размеры?

Размеры атласа выделяются красными линиями

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mokf5.png]